# SaveAs and delete same time c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

*Here i want to save the image file and delete it after checking its dimensions if it fulfills the criteria, the code is given below*

```
int ActualWidth, ActualHeight;
bool checker = true;
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count;i++)
{
   postedData = files[i];
   string ext = Path.GetExtension(postedData.FileName);
   string namefile = "ProdImg" + objutl.GetUniqueNumbers(5) + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
   postedData.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/imgProd/") + namefile + ext);
   string completFileName = Server.MapPath("~/imgProd/") + namefile + ext;
   System.Drawing.Image Img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(completFileName);
   ActualWidth = Img.Width;
   ActualHeight = Img.Height;
   if (ActualHeight >= 900 && ActualWidth >= 900)
   {
        fname += namefile + ext + ":::";
   }
   else
   {
        fname = string.Concat(fname.Reverse().Skip(3).Reverse());
        string[] imgArr;
        imgArr = fname.Split(new string[] { ":::" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string deletefile;
        for (int k = 0; k < imgArr.Length; k++)
        {
           deletefile = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/imgProd/"), imgArr[k]);
           if (System.IO.File.Exists(deletefile))
           {    
              System.IO.File.Delete(deletefile);
           }
        }
        checker = false;
        break;
    }
```

*Error given is **not handled in user code
Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'D:\Namco\PropertyWebSite\atelierkabana\New folder (3)\atelierkabana\atelierkabana\imgProd\ProdImg9635606022017145437.jpg' because it is being used by another process.***

*Which is given on this line of code :*
**System.IO.File.Delete(deletefile);**
*at the time of Debug.I want to save and delete multiple files on this project how can i achieve that .. ?*

Comment: You're not disposing your `Img`.

Comment: actually yes if dimensions are are true then it saves either ways if it isn't it'll delete those files which have been saved earlier as you can see the code above.

Comment: Used the dispose() method but still showing same issue

Comment: same error **Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'D:\Namco\PropertyWebSite\atelierkabana\New folder (3)\atelierkabana\atelierkabana\imgProd\ProdImg4912406022017153713.jpg' because it is being used by another process.**